# Alembic Migrations without Database

Tags: sqlalchemy, django-south, django-migrations, alembic

Is it possible to have Alembic [auto-generate migrations](https://alembic.readthedocs.org/en/latest/autogenerate.html) without it having access to the database?

For example django / south are able to do this by [comparing the current version of a `Model` against a previous snapshot of the `Model`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/migrations/#migration-files).

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: I did not figure this out.

Comment: See: https://bitbucket.org/zzzeek/alembic/issues/117/autogen-from-persisted-metadata

Answer (score 2):

No, this isn't possible. In [the relevant issue](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/alembic/issues/117) zzzeek said

> while the reflection-based comparison has its issues, it really is a very fundamental assumption these days particularly in the openstack world where autogen features are used in unit test suites to ensure the migrated schema matches the model. I don't have plans right now to pursue the datafile-based approach, it would be an enormous undertaking for a system that people seem to be mostly OK with as is.

Though an alternative approach could be to spin up a new database on demand, run the migrations from empty to head, generate against it, then discard the database.